# Mongoid and extended JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to bypass a JSON aggregation query to aggregation pipeline of MongoDB.

For doing that I have this endpoint on my RoR app

```
def index
  Lead.collection.aggregate(JSON.parse(params[:query]))
end
```

And I send this JSON from my frontend

```
[
   {
      "$match": {
        "statuses.created_at": {
          "$gte": {
            "$date": "1539369174"
          }
        }
      }
    }
]
```

The problem is that I'm not getting no result because "$date" filter is not working properly.

In mongo shell I'm getting results.

Comment: Can you clarify "not working"? Do you get an error? No results?

Comment: I'm not getting results with Mongoid but I'm getting results doing the same query in MongoDB shell

Comment: There is a format spec for ["MongoDB extended JSON"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) but the Ruby driver knows nothing of this and does not support it. I'm not aware of any third party implementation for ruby either, but projects exist in other languages you could use for reference i.e [extended-json](https://github.com/mongodb-js/extended-json). Just to also note that your timestamp value in the date appears to be in seconds, where the spec is for milliseconds, So even the source data appears incorrect.

Comment: I will say that it appears somewhat ironic that the only reason the ruby driver does not support this is because the assigned maintainer did not appear to "get the memo" at the time the task was assigned. The history seems to indicate they saw "JSON" and just dismissed it as having nothing to do with them. See [RUBY-780](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-780) for details